# How to preserve file permission mode when extracting a zip archive in Python?

Tags: python, compression, unzip, mode

I have created a zip archive in Python with `shutil.make_archive`, but when I extract it with both `shutil.unpack_archive` and `zipfile.ZipFile(file).extractall()` the file modes are changed as:

```
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

Currently I have to make a subprocess call to `run('unzip ...')` for it to work? Is there a Python builtin that I can use to preserve the file modes?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no inbuild way to preserve the permission. I think the argument is, that it is not part of the zip-standard and a unix-extension.

There are two workaround I know:

- inspect the attributes stored in the zip file in `ZipInfo.external_attr` and setting it yourself with `os.chmod`, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326428/zipfile-in-python-file-permission)
- calling the unix tool unzip from within python that does the right thing, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840029/file-permissions-lost-after-unzipping-with-zipfile)

One thing I don't know is if `shutil.make_archive` stores these extended permissions. If not one would use the same stragies above for zipping...